# GDB Print for String is not displaying value correctly

Tags: gdb

[Weird String Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSgN4.png)

When I want to check what the current value of the string is, it is showing that weird message at $1. I just want to know what the value is :(

New to debugging with GDB, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

> is showing that weird message at $1

There is *nothing* weird about it.

Implementing a `std::string` class that performs well for both short and long strings is somewhat non-trivial, and you are looking at the internals of the implementation.

> I just want to know what the value is

The value is obviously `lol`.

If you are not interested in the internals of `std::string`, you should likely use `print x.c_str()` instead of `print x`.

**Update:**

> Inside gdb when I do print x only: why does it do that instead of just the value of the string.

GDB *does* just show you the value of the `std::string`, it just happens that the internal state of `std::string` is complicated.

> Is it because it is not a primitive type.

Yes.

> how did you know you had to do x.cstr() etc

Because I use `std::string` a lot, and know what methods it provides.

> Say I had a vector and I wanted just the elements in the vector, what would I do?

You could print elements of the vector: `print v[0]`, `print v[1]`, etc.

Some implementations of `std::vector` provide GDB pretty-printers which make this easier. For example, on a fairly modern Linux system, you would see something like this:

```
(gdb) list
1   #include <vector>
2
3   int main()
4   {
5     std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,7,6,5,4};
6     return v.size();
7   }

(gdb) p v
$1 = std::vector of length 7, capacity 7 = {1, 2, 3, 7, 6, 5, 4}
```

If your implementation doesn't provide such pretty printer, writing one would be a great learning exercise. Documentation [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Writing-a-Pretty_002dPrinter.html).

Comment: Just for my understanding, I need to clarify a couple things. Sorry for the stupid questions.

Inside gdb when I do print x only: why does it do that instead of just the value of the string. Is it because it is not a primitive type.

Also, how did you know you had to do x.cstr() etc 

Say I had a vector and I wanted just the elements in the vector, what would I do? 

That will clarify my understanding for how to use gdb for my needs.